# entity framework code first private set for identity column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

It seems to me that almost by default all code first POCO's should have private setters for their primary key a.k.a. auto-generated Id.

Like this -
 public int id { get; private set; }

Is this an incorrect assumption? I do not want my API to allow setting of an auto-generated column.

Comment: This is just an opinion that can only be answered by other opinions. Not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is not an opinion but a part of the EF code first scaffolding.  As you can see below in my comment this has already caused a problem in our code base where an auto generated ID is now being updated by the code and not in the database.

Comment: You question, *as stated*, is just an opinion (which, by the way, I could easily agree with). It's not a specific programming problem, which is the kind of question that does belong on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing a public setter should not be an issue since it is unadvised to even expose this POCO outside the Data Access Object layer..

Exposing a POCO decorated with a specific framework's attributes, or even a POCO which discloses some kind of information regarding storage (Entity Relational Database, in this instance) is a bad practice.

Consider wrapping it in an interface and returning it as an instance of that interface. This way you get to enjoy the best of both worlds. Exposing the properties which are necessary and allowing to set only a part of them.

In any case, I do not think that EF will like the private setter thing too much.

Comment: Interstingly enough what I feared has crept into our code.  This is in the POST of the Organization entity.  The id here is an identity in the database   -  organization.id = db.Organizations.Count() > 0 ? db.Organizations.Max(x => x.id) + 1 : 0;